# Add a custom line item type with custom fields when my module is active

Tags: commerce, entities

I'm developing a module that adds on to Drupal Commerce that requires a custom line item type (LIT) along with additional fields on the LIT. With this hook I can add the LIT.

```
function package_designer_commerce_line_item_type_info_alter(&$line_item_types) {
     $lineItemType = array
    (
        'name' => "new product line item type",
        'description' => "A customized product line item type",
        'product' => true,
        'add_form_submit_value' => "Add product",
        'base' => "commerce_product_line_item"
    );
    $line_item_types['new_product_line_item_type'] = $lineItemType;

}
```

And it appears in the LIT list under the configuration menu. But when I click on Manage Fields it doesn't have the same list of as the regular commerce line item type, which is what I thought the `base` entry was meant to do. That is secondary though to my actual problem.

I want my LIT to have a specific field attached to it without having to provide instructions on how to go through the admin interface and create it. This might mean that instead of using that hook I need to use the `.install` file but I'm new to Drupal and would like to start with the recommended method instead of developing bad habits.

*Update*

It turns out `base` doesn't do what I thought it did. It only sets the line item up for using the default callbacks that start with 'commerce_product_line_item_type'. To actually make my LIT have the same base fields as the commerce product one I need to add this to my module

```
function package_designer_enable() {
    commerce_product_line_item_configuration(array('type'=>'new_product_line_item_type'));
}
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was using the Features module to write the code that created my setup, then copied it in to my module.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @pcambra, the hook to define custom line items is [hook_commerce_line_item_type_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.api.php/function/implementations/hook_commerce_line_item_type_info/7).

The `base` key is used to build the name of some callback functions. If not specified, it defaults to the line item type name.

One of the possible callbacks is "configuration", and it is invoked when the line item is first detected by Commerce. In this callback is where you should create the fields/instances related to your line item type. Commerce already does it in commerce_product_reference module. See [commerce_product_reference_commerce_line_item_type_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21product_reference%21commerce_product_reference.module/function/commerce_product_reference_commerce_line_item_type_info/7) and [commerce_product_line_item_configuration](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21product_reference%21commerce_product_reference.module/function/commerce_product_line_item_configuration/7) for reference.

Also, you can consult [this blog post](http://atlantic-canary.net/es/ease-the-creation-of-fields-and-instances-programatically) for some tricks to ease the creation of fields/instances.

Answer (score 0):

That would work in the case that your line item type is a "product" one, you can check how Commerce Shipping does this in case it weren't product types.

Instead of using hook_commerce_line_item_type_info_alter, you should be using [hook_commerce_line_item_type_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.api.php/function/implementations/hook_commerce_line_item_type_info/7) to define your line item type.

Alternatively, you can use [Commerce Customizable Products](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) module if you don't want to code yours.

For creating fields into Line item types or any entity, check [Commerce discount](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) or [Commerce recurring framework](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring).

Commerce recurring uses an hook_enable approach ([link](http://drupalcode.org/project/commerce_recurring.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/commerce_recurring.module#l71)), making sure that a field is not created if it previously existed whereas Commerce discount uses a similar approach but in hook_flush_caches() ([link](http://drupalcode.org/project/commerce_discount.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/commerce_discount.module#l170))

Comment: I switched to using hook_commerce_line_item_type_info andit works fine, but it doesn't address my question, which is how to attach fields to that line_item_type during module installation

Comment: Oh, I see your question now, creating fields for an entity is normally tricky, but you can find good examples on how to do this in both Commerce Discounts and Commerce Recurring Framework (not specifically for line items, but the technique is the same). Updated answer